# contact form 7 add custom variable

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

My use case is very simple. I have a bunch of books on my site and close to each one there is a button to pop up a "Request Info" contact form to fill.

I'd like that when the user clicks on "Request Info", the email that is sent from CF7 contains the book title too, which I then use into my `wpcf7_before_send_mail` function.

In other words, if there a way to use a parameter into the CF7 shortcode, so that I can then retrieve it into the before_send function?

Something like:

```
[contact-form-7 id=1234 title="My form" myvalue="45DC67"]
```

Thanks

Fabio

Comment: Sorry, I moved this question to the Wordpress Development site, here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176676/contact-form-7-send-custom-variable-to-form

Comment: This may help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105974/33529